# Cookie based sqli

Tags: sql-injection, cookies

I have identified a website vulnerable to sql injection via a authentication token. Does anyone know where I can find a tutorial / example of cookie based sql injection?

Comment: Have you tried to search yourself?

Comment: Yes. Its ok I am currently talking with offsec staff now on irc as they are the ones providing the course and can probably help me the most. I will post back later with some useful information if no one beats me to it.

Comment: Please don't ask course questions here - you have the teaching staff to help you as well as the wealth of Google.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlmap (http://sqlmap.org/) enables you to test injection by cookie with the switch

```
./sqlmap.py --cookie=""
```

In addition to the other switches you would otherwise use.

Note, you will likely need to enter the cookie in full in the value mentioned above and dictate which parameter sqlmap will need to use.

https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Sqlmap-Tricks-for-Advanced-SQL-Injection/ May be useful to you here.

Otherwise you can test this manually with curl with the

```
curl -b
```

Command-line switch which indicates your cookies.

Curl's manpage may be useful if you need to do more than a simple get request to get to the exploitable portion of the webapp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer useful but not quite what i was after. I did `cookiename=1111111'` sql threw an error. I was looking to manipulate the cookie i managed to finally get in. with index.php?cookiename=blah using sqlmap. Instead of using tamper data.

Comment: Well, the URL that you're trying to use specifies a get variable of cookiename which has the value of 111111, in php this would look like you're requesting $_GET['cookiename'] as opposed to $_COOKIE['cookiename'].  Does this make sense?  Can you show me the sqlmap commandline you're trying to use?

Comment: It's ok I got in at the start i was not using sqlmap I was trying to manually do it. The sql command i ended up using was `sqlmap --os-shell -u http://x.x.x.x/index.php?cookiename=1111`

Comment: Like I said, the URL you're providing does not designate a cookie parameter, using it in the get field of the URL designates cookiename as a get request.  You need to do the following: `sqlmap -u http://x.x.x.x/index.php cookie="cookiename=1111"`

Comment: index.php is not vulnerable though. When i did x.x.x.x/index.php?cookiename=111 it actually set "cookiename" to 111. The name cookiename is actually contains a sessionid

Comment: Ah, my thinking was that you were looking to manually modify the cookie header.  What a bizarre thing to a webapp to do, which app is this? Is its code available anywhere?

Comment: Yes it's a open source online store/shop web application. I will release the code on exploit-db tomorrow as the vulnerability is currently not public. I will let you know when it's published.

Comment: @NahumG `$_REQUEST` contains all `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` values.